# Curl operation proof

Tags: notation, curl

I am new to subscript notation, and I am having a problem with the proof practice below,
$$\frac{1}{2}\vec{\nabla}(\vec{f}\cdot\vec{f}) = \vec{f} \times \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{f} + (\vec{f} \cdot \vec{\nabla})\vec{f}$$

I started from the first term RHS, and write it as below,
$$\begin{aligned}\vec{f}\times\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{f} &= \epsilon_{ijk}f_i\nabla_{j}\epsilon_{klm}f_m \\ &=\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{klm}f_i\nabla_jf_m \\ &=(\delta_{im}\delta_{jl}-\delta_{il}\delta_{jm})f_i\nabla_jf_m \\ &=\delta_{im}\delta_{jl}f_i\nabla_jf_m - \delta_{il}\delta_{jm}f_i\nabla_jf_m \\ &=f_m\nabla_jf_m - f_l\nabla_jf_j \\ &=f\cdot f\nabla -f(\nabla\cdot f) \end{aligned}$$

Is this correct? How to continue the proof?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You have an error in your Levi Cevita simplification. We have
$$
\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{klm} = \epsilon_{kij} \epsilon_{klm} = (\delta_{il}\delta_{jm} - \delta_{im}\delta_{jl}).
$$

Comment: Hi, sorry I just realized that I typed in the subscript order for the second epsilon wrong, it should be kml instead of klm. Is it still the same error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1) The equality $f_m \nabla_j f_m=f\cdot f\nabla$ isn't sound: $\nabla_k$ is differentiation, and you can't blithely exchange it it past the function $f_m$.
2) In your first line, you have one free index $l$. First off, this index should appear on the LHS as well ($(\vec{f}\times (\nabla\times \vec{f})_l$). Second, your second-to-last line has free index $j$ in its first term instead. Free indices have to remain consistent.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! What is the order of operation for $\vec{f} \times \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{f}$? Is it $(\vec{f} \times (\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{f}))$? I still got a term as $f_k\nabla_lf_k$, does it equal to $f_k(\nabla_lf_k)$? Thank you!